# How do record audio from a bluetooth headset on the iPad/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, bluetooth, jawbone

I can hear audio from bluetooth headsets on my iPad/iPhone, but I can't record audio in Applications from the headset.  Even the sample "SpeakHere" application doesn't record audio from the headset.

Is there a reason audio out works seamlessly but audio in doesn't work?  I'm trying to use an Aleph Jawbone headset.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default audio sessions don't support audio input via a bluetooth headset. It has to be explicitly accounted for in the code (which isn't true for bluetooth audio output).

That probably explains why lots of apps you're trying aren't supporting your headset: the developers haven't considered the edge case. The SpeakHere example code provided by Apple also doesn't support Bluetooth input (nice if it did, right?).

Here's the sample code Apple give in the docs to enable bluetooth input (assuming you already have an audio session):

```
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;

AudioSessionSetProperty (
    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
    sizeof (allowBluetoothInput),
    &allowBluetoothInput
);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is that property a global for all Audio sessions used in a given application?

Comment: I don't think so, no. You'll need to set it for each audio session.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a way to do this, however you must have a jailbroken iDevice (I only know that it works for the iPhone.) Open Cydia and search for an app called "Bluetooth Mono SBSettings", download and install that onto your device, and you ought to be able to not only record audio from a bluetooth headset, but also hear sound through the headset that you would normally hear as if you were wearing headphones. This works on any (as far as im aware of) bluetooth headset. I have an iPhone 3g, and i have a Motorola H390 as my headset. I hope it works!